# Does Cobalt renderer thread support a fix resolution video frame when playing 360 Video in seamless

Tags: cobalt

We are going to implement 360 Video(Spherical Video) on our device, our video output resolution should be set while creating the player. 
  As I know, 360 Video will only display part of the video. Is it OK for Cobalt renderer thread that the video resolution may be different from SbPlayerGetCurrentFrame? For example: when the 360 video resolution changed from 4K to 1080P, the resolution you get from SbPlayerGetCurrentFrame is always 4K.

Answer (score 0):

That should be no problem, as long as the SbDecodeTargetInfo structure is setup to correctly identify the content region within the produced texture.  For example, make sure that SbDecodeTargetInfoPlane::content_region is setup to properly identify the 1080p region of content within the 4K texture.